# Mocking datetime.now using pytest-mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a function `func_to_mock` in module `module_to_mock.py`. My unit test is located in `test_func_to_mock.py`

I am trying to mock `datetime.datetime.now`, however, I am struggling. I get the error `TypeError: cannot set 'now' attribute of immutable type 'datetime.datetime'`.

What am I missing here?

module_to_mock.py:

```
# module_to_mock.py

import datetime


def func_to_mock() -> datetime.datetime:
    return datetime.datetime.now()
```

My unit test:

```
# test_func_to_mock.py

import datetime

from pytest_mock import MockFixture

import port_bt.module_to_mock


def test_func_to_mock(mocker: MockFixture) -> None:
    # This will error with:
    # TypeError: cannot set 'now' attribute of immutable type 'datetime.datetime'
    mocked_date = mocker.patch(
        "datetime.datetime.now", return_value=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0)
    )

    assert port_bt.module_to_mock.func_to_mock() == mocked_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, you cannot patch Python standard library classes that are implemented in C (according to [these](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#partial-mocking) `unittest.mock` docs). However, you can patch the `datetime` package like so:

**test_func_to_mock.py**

```python
import datetime
from pytest_mock import MockFixture

import module_to_mock


def test_func_to_mock(mocker: MockFixture) -> None:

    mocked_datetime = mocker.patch(
        "module_to_mock.datetime",  # 1
    )
    jan_31 = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0)
    mocked_datetime.datetime.now.return_value = jan_31

    assert module_to_mock.func_to_mock() == jan_31 # 2
```

Note that

1. It is often better to patch the module under test rather than the datetime package directly. See also [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).
2. We expect the date time value to be returned, not the mock object (which is what your assertion expects, I think).

---

In response to the question about fixtures, I would say that sounds like a very good idea. You should be able to `yield` the mock object from a fixture so that you don't have to `patch()` in every test function:

**test_func_with_fixture.py**

```python
import datetime
from typing import Final, Generator
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockFixture

import module_to_mock

JAN_31: Final[datetime.datetime] = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0)

@pytest.fixture
def datetime_fixture(mocker: MockFixture) -> Generator[MagicMock, None, None]:
    mocked_datetime = mocker.patch(
        "module_to_mock.datetime",
    )
    mocked_datetime.datetime.now.return_value = JAN_31
    yield mocked_datetime
    

def test_func_to_mock(datetime_fixture: MagicMock) -> None:
    assert module_to_mock.func_to_mock() == JAN_31
```

Comment: This is working fine, thanks. As a follow up, can I put the mocked_datetime into a pytest fixture? I need this mock in multiple unit tests.